# feathersjs/nodejs sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am using feathers js and sequelize. I already have existing models like users .

Now my question is if I wanted to add a new column to user model/database for example user_firstname should I directly add that to the model.js ? or I need to create migrations for that ?

How does it affect locally and on stating or production ? Thank you.

## Sample models.user , snippet

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const users = sequelizeClient.define('users', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(320),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `sequelize.sync()` then you should create a migration, modify a model, build the app, deploy the app, run migrations on a DB that is related to the deployed app to make sure that the app is corresponding to a DB (a structure and data).

Comment: , so its not ideal to directly change the model ?

Comment: If you change a model and don't use `sync` then this change will never appear in a DB. If you don't use `sync` you should create migrations and modify models synchronously.